# Change object type in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a desktop application using C# and EF6.
For some reasons (One would be the complexity of the structure of the models) I've decided to use only on DbContext for the whole project, instead of create and dispose every time I need to add, update, delete or fetch any data.

Let's say I have 2 Models

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CollegeStudent : Student
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel and instantiate it after I add an item to the collection.

I add and Student object to the database in the following way

```
public void AddStudent()
{
    var obj = new Student() { Name = "Mike" };
    _context.Set<Student>().Add(obj);
    StudentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_context.Set<Student>().ToList());
}
```

And when I want to change the type of the Student to the CollegeStudent I use the following piece of code

```
public void AddCollegeStudent(CollegeStudent obj)
{
    var original = _context.Set<Student>().Find(obj.Id);

    var obj = new Student() 
    {
        Id = original.Id,
        Name = original.Name,
        Course = "Some Course",
    }
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO CollegeStudent (Id, Course) VALUES (obj.Id, '" + obj.Course + "');");

    StudentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_context.Set<Student>().ToList());
}
```

It perfectly works and insert the CollegeStudent details in the database but when getting the list of students from the database it throws the following 
exception:

All objects in the EntitySet 'Students' must have unique primary keys. However, an instance of type 'CollegeStudent' and an instance of type 'Student' both have the same primary key value, 'EntitySet=Students;Id=4'

Answer (score 2):

> I've decided to use only on DbContext for the whole project, instead of create and dispose every time I need to add, update, delete or fetch any data.

There's your problem...

This is one reason why you *shouldn't* you a single `DbContext` for an entire app - changes to underlying data can make the data in your context invalid.  Contexts are *meant* to be created and disposed with every DB operation.  They are lightweight so creating lots of them shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: If I don't want to use a single DbContext, then each time I add or update an item to the context, I have to reload all the objects to the ObservableCollectionw which is bound to a ListBox to display all the items to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you are likely trying to keep things as straightforward as possible but it might be worthwhile separating your concerns sooner rather than later.

Assuming this is a XAML UI you could make use of a framework like MVVM  Light or Prism

- https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx

If not the basics are you want some kind of mediator (http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/mediator.aspx)

So the idea is you will have some kind of service class that makes a call to save the data, then raises the message/event saying that the data was updated. 
You would register a handler for when that event is raises to update the view model accordingly.

Hope this makes sense.